# Pull the previous sibling element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

You can use `margin-right`, for example, to push a next sibling as seen below:

```css
#parent {
  background: tan;
  font-size: 0;
}

#parent * {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#child1 {
  background: teal;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

#child2 {
  background: olive;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

I know there is no *previous sibling* selector in CSS. However, I wonder if there's a workaround so `#child2` can pull `#child1` to a distance of say, `20px`. Here's a before-after screenshot:

[image]

**Note**: I don't want to give a `margin` value to `#child1` or alter the HTML. The effect should be achieved using `#child2` only.

Comment: It depends on directions. if you are using `rtl` you may move `child1`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by pull? margin-left:20px; can be added to #child1 to make it closer to #child2 by 20px.

Comment: There's no *previous sibling* selector in CSS. But there is a clean and valid way to simulate that behavior with CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36118012/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B: Please post this as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Mike, I'm just not entirely clear on the overall objective. What exactly do you mean by *pull `.child1`*? Can you post an image?

Comment: @Michael_B: Sure! Here's a before-after screenshot.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey: Would you mind providing a demo?

Comment: @Mike I don't understand the question. In the first example image `#child2` is located where it is because of the 100px margin-right, but in the second image it has remained where it is, but `#child1` is closer...

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me, it doesn't touch #child1 but #parent. *Changed to classes instead of ids just to show the same code works for all.*

```css
.parent {
  background: tan;
  font-size: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.parent * {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.child1 {
  background: teal;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.child2 {
  background: olive;
}

.child3 {
  background: red;
}

.parent > div:only-child {
  margin-right:100px;
  margin-left:0px;
}

.parent > div {
  margin-right:20px;
}

.parent > div:first-child:not(:last-child) {
  margin-left:60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no previous sibling selector using pure CSS.
The possible workaround is using CSS flexbox.

First, set display property as `flex` to the #parent element. reverse the order of displaying child elements

```
<div id="child2"></div>
<div id="child1"></div>
```

We can correct this visually by setting

> order:-1 to `#child1`.

Then we will address the #child1 by using

```
#parent>div:first-child+div
```

This means the next div after the first div, ie, `#child1`. Then set the styles.

```
#parent>div:first-child+div {
margin-right: 20px;
margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```css
#parent {
  background: tan;
  display: flex;
}

#parent * {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#child1 {
  background: teal;
  order: -1;
}

#child2 {
  background: olive;
}

#parent>div:first-child+div {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child2"></div>
  <div id="child1"></div>
</div>
```

For better understandability, hover the `#child2` then you can see the color change of its previous sibling.

```
#child2:hover+div {
background: brown;
}
```

```css
#parent {
  background: tan;
  display: flex;
}

#parent * {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#child1 {
  background: teal;
  order: -1;
}

#child2 {
  background: olive;
}

#parent>div:first-child+div {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

#child2:hover+div {
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child2"></div>
  <div id="child1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a CSS-only solution without touching the HTML.

Comment: @Mike What you mean by without touching HTML ?

Comment: @Mike, We just reverse the order of child elements and reset that using CSS. So visually they look the same.

Comment: Please run the code snippet. Hover child2 and you will see the change on its previous sibling.

Comment: @Mike Pure CSS solution is not possible AFAIK

Comment: @GeethuJose I am not the DV. But it seems like you added irrelevant codes ( the hover). Is this your own code or taken from somewhere else?

Comment: I added the hover code to show, how the previous sibling is selected

Comment: Agreed. But the first priority is to answer the question only. Then, for illustration, you can add something like, _The working is..._ and explain then add _to verify this_ or something and then you can do the rest. But a fresh code for the OP should be recommended.

Comment: @SagarV: Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @GeethuJose: "reverse the order of displaying child elements" Thanks for the answer, but there's a misunderstanding: when you do that, `#child1` becomes the second child , and that's why I asked you not to disorder them.

Comment: @Mike: To get the desired result, you have to reverse the order of children in HTML and then reset that in CSS. As I told you pure CSS solution is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is what the OP is asking, but the following code, *pulls* the first child only when the second child exists, so in a sense, the second child pulls the first one :)

```
#parent > div:first-child:nth-last-child(2) {
    margin-left:60px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/06urn796/

Removing the second child, leaves the first one intact:
https://jsfiddle.net/06urn796/1/

Answer (score 0):

According to your replies on the given answers your question should have been:

**Can you 'pull the previous sibling element' by using CSS (only), and without changing the HTML?**

The answer to that question is as simple as unsatisfying:

**No, there is not.**

Not even when you change the reading direction. I am sorry.

Answer (score -1):

```css
#parent {
  background: tan;
  font-size: 0;
}

#parent * {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#parent div{
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

#child1 {
  background: teal;
}

#child2 {
  background: olive;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```